# Why are quotes on the blockquote showing in a new line?

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

This might be quite simple but I can't make it work. I need to add quotes to a paragraph that should be limited to 2 lines. And is showing as picture

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjxQg.png)

or

**“**

**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis porta enim, et pulvinar erat**

**”**

I would need to remove the new line after de first quote and before the last one to get something like this:

**“**
**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis porta enim, et pulvinar erat**
**”**

Here's the code:

```html
<blockquote className="mt-6 subtitle-2-regular">
    “<p className="line-clamp-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis porta enim, et pulvinar erat</p>”
</blockquote>
```

Please help. Thanks!

PS: I'm using tailwind's line-clamp extension to limit the lines to 2.

Comment: Can you please add a working code.

Comment: We need to see what CSS is actually being produced so please include a working snippet in your question - for example is the -webkit-line-clamp property being used and what formatting is being applied to the blockquote? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with putting code into your question.

Answer (score 1):

**`<p>` tag has display: block by default so it will be on a new line.**

I would suggest you to put your quotes inside of the `<p>`.

Similar to this:

```
<blockquote className="mt-6 subtitle-2-regular">
  <p className="line-clamp-2">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis porta
    enim, et pulvinar erat"
  </p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! That work but, line-clamp plugin removes the las quote. That's why I moved the quotes outside

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is making the quotes be inside of the <**p**> tag

Or if u also want to cite anything is add a <**q**> tag inside the <**p**> tag.

As the example of below.

```html
<blockquote className="mt-6 subtitle-2-regular">
    <p className="line-clamp-2"><q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis porta enim, et pulvinar erat</q></p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, but the line-clapm extension cuts the last quote out. That's why I moved outisde the <p> tag

Answer (score 0):

As the quotes are a visual clue rather than an integral part of the meaning we can add them using pseudo before and after elements.

To get them positioned correctly this snippet has wrapped the p element in another element, the sole purpose of which is to be positioned so the pseudo elements can be positioned in relation to it.

The snippet is in pure CSS, using the -webkit-line-clamp and associated properties. This automatically adds ellipsis. You will need to look at the exact code that tailwind produces to get the positioning corrected if necessary.

```css
blockquote div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

blockquote p::before {
  content: '\201C ';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

blockquote p::after {
  content: '\201D ';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

blockquote p {
  width: 300px;
  /* just to force lines to wrap for this demo */
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<blockquote className="mt-6 subtitle-2-regular">
  <div>
    <p className="line-clamp-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis porta enim, et pulvinar erat</p>
  </div>
</blockquote>
```